# Do TN and IPS displays are subject to diffraction?

Tags: optics

Sometimes displays with the same resolution, diagonal and aspect ratio appear to have different level of sharpness .

In optics there is this concept of diffraction and if you can lower your diffraction the image gets sharper .

It's possible to get a simple explanation about why displays that appear to be so similar end up having such diversified performances ?

It's also true that monitors usually have multiple layers on top of the panel, usually glass or plastic, but still, the final result is different and I would like to know why and which properties have the major impact on the final result .

Comment: Tip: Try to avoid abbreviations in title in order to make the post more accessible to a wider audience.

Comment: @Qmechanic yes but anyone who knows what a display is is familiar with such acronym, plus they are quite unique and not common to other disciplines as far as I know. The title will just be longer and less readable in this case.

Comment: Don't overestimate others' familiarity with what seems easy to you. I learned what TN means long after I learned what a display is, and I have no idea what IPS is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two displays have the same pixel sizes they will have the same amount of diffraction. The larger changes in image quality will come from a number of factors:

1. The thickness of the display. The thicker the display, the lower the viewing angle
2. The LC material, this can have impact on the brightness dynamic range, among other factors.
3. The quality of the backlighting
4. The display electronics, many cheaper displays can only display a limited number of colours

All of these combine together to effect the quality of the display.

Comment: and how the dot pitch can change this ? How does that features scales ? Is the dot pitch affecting the diffraction at all ?

Comment: The dot pitch (pixels per m) is the reciprocal of the pixel size. The higher the pitch, the more diffraction but it will be same diffraction for displays with the same pitch.